# Animation on TextView not working after changing textview Location

Tags: android, animation, textview

I am using a textview Who's position is changed on touch by following code

```
 tvPostText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            if (event.getPointerCount() == 3) {
                tvPostText.setRotation(rotation(event));
            } else if (event.getPointerCount() == 1) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    v.setX(event.getRawX() - v.getWidth() / 2.0f);
                    v.setY(event.getRawY() - v.getHeight() / 2.0f);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

I am applying rotate animation on it. If i change the location of textview by finger touch then animation in not working properly. can some one suggerst me how can i apply animation on textview even after change of textview Position.

Following is animation code: -

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f);
            anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            anim.setDuration(3000);
            tvPostText.startAnimation(animRotate);
```

Comment: call `tvPostText.setRotation(rotation(event));` in `if (event.getPointerCount() == 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Animator

```
            ObjectAnimator objectAnimator=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tvPostText,"rotation",0f,360f);
            objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            objectAnimator.setDuration(3000);
            objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
            objectAnimator.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `clearAnimation()` on your textview after animation is done. It helped me.